# Undefined variable en una vista individual de laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, laravel

buenas me encuentro realizando una aplicacion de biblioteca en laravel ala hora de realizar una vista individual de la base de datos usando la funcion show de controlador lo hago de la siguiente manera

```
public function show($id)
{
    $libros = Libro::find($id);
    if (!is_null($libros))

        return view('libro.show', compact('libro'));
    else
        Session::flash('message','404 Libro no existente');
        return Redirect::to('libro');
}
```

hasta aqui sin problemas hasta usando la funcion dd($libros->titulo,$libros->idioma); me devuelve los resultados correctos
pero a la hora de llamar al metodo show.blade.php me sale el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

porfavor si alguien entiende que error estoy cometiendo se le agradece aclarar. anexo la ruta y el codigo del show

show.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content') 

@include('alerts.request')

<h2>{{$libro->titulo }}</h2>
<p>{{$libro->idioma }}</p>

@endsection
```

y la ruta

```
Route::resource('libro','LibroController');
route::get('libro/{id}/show', 'LibroController@show')->where(['id' => '[0-9]+']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es un error bastante simple, no estás definiendo en ninguna parte la variable `$libro`, en cambio sí estás definiendo `$libros`.

Por lo que se ve en tu código, al parecer es solo definir `$libro` en vez de `$libros`.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $libro = Libro::find($id);
    if (!is_null($libro))

        return view('libro.show', compact('libro'));
    else
        Session::flash('message','404 Libro no existente');
        return Redirect::to('libro');
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, ese era el problema muchas gracias

Comment: @SantiagoAvila - Deberías aceptar la respuesta si te ha solucionado el problema. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ponerlo así si quieres mantener el nombre de la variable:

```
return view('libro.show', ['libro' => $libros]);
```